# Compacting a conditional statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hi I have conditional clause that I am wondering can be written differently with less line of code.

```
If Exists(select id from tTest where tId=@tId)
begin
   set @flag=1;
end
else begin
  set @flag=0;
end;
```

Is there a better way to write this so it is less code and does the same work? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `@flag` is defined as a `BIT`:

```
SELECT @flag = COUNT(*) FROM dbo.tTest WHERE tId = @tId;
```

Anything but `0` will set `@flag = 1`.

However, I will say that focusing on terse code is not always going to do you any favors. Do you care more about short code or fast code? Depending on indexes and cardinality, the following code - while longer - has a chance to short circuit and perform less reads than a `COUNT`:

```
SELECT @flag = CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.tTest WHERE tId = @tId) 
  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
```

Comment: +1 for the second approach.  It's not the most compact but it's easily understandable.

Answer (score 1):

You also may implement it without any aggregates and predicates like "exists". Just:

```
declare @flag [bit] set @flag = 0
select @flag = 1 from tTest where tId=@tId
```

Comment: Ah, yes. That quirk of not modifying variables at all if the query returns no records. Clever.

Answer (score 0):

Well there's compact...

```
select @flag = isnull(power(max(id),0),0) from tTest where tId = @tId
```

but it's maybe a bit unconventional.

slightly less compact, but more straightforward...

```
select @flag = case when max(id) is null then 0 else 1 end from tTest where tId = @tId
```

These assume, of course, that null isn't a valid value for the column.